# Destroy session using jira-python REST client

Tags: python, rest, python-jira

I am trying to invalidate the session using jira-python rest client. How can I achieve this feature, is it built in or needs to be implemented?

I tried looking at all the APIs available in client.py and there seems to be no way to destroy or invalidate a session.

Another question that follow is, do I have to authenticate on every REST call made by the client? Currently that is what I am doing.

Comment: I usually create one jira client at the beginning of program and then just use reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

JIRA invalidates session after 5 hours, from version 4.3 onwards.

Found the answer here - https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/15277569/python-jira-client-destroy-session

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, one of the reasons why is called REST api is because you do not have to do anything with the session.